# Can't save the image after using GPUImage filter

Tags: ios, image, save, gpuimage

Some of my code at follow:

```
GPUImagePicture*  staticPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

GPUImageSaturationFilter * filter = [[GPUImageSaturationFilter alloc] init];
[filter setSaturation:0.2];
[filter addTarget:((GPUImageView *)gpuImageView)];

[staticPicture addTarget:filter];
[staticPicture processImage];

_saveImage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

[self.testImageView setImage:_saveImage];
```

I want use imageFromCurrentFramebuffer to get the image with filter, but i get always nil.Use [self.testImageView setImage:_saveImage] always get blank.

Do i get the image in a wrong way?Any sugesst is welcome. A lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
[filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
```

on a line right before you call

```
[staticPicture processImage];
```

Otherwise, the filter won't know to hang on to its processed framebuffer long enough for you to capture your image.